# Passing/Retrieving pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, parameter-passing, return-value

When passing or retrieving an object by pointer in C++, it is known that the object itself wont be copied, but what about the pointer, so does the recieving fuction handle the same pointer of the object or a copy of that pointer and hence every pointer should be assigned to null when not needed anymore.

Comment: The lifetime of a pointer to an object and the object itself are not necessary linked. It is the responsibility of the developer to know the semantics of both.

Comment: A pointer is just a number (memory address) - you can copy it all you like without changing anything.

Comment: This is an XY question if ever I saw one. Why do you think it might be necessary to "assign to null when not needed anymore"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When passing a pointer in c++ (i.e. `foo(some_object* p)`)  you actually pass the value of the pointer, where the object resides. The value itself is a copy, meaning that if you do `p = NULL;` inside your function, that won't change the original pointer, but the address it points to holds the same original object.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class obj{
public:
  int a;
};

void foo(obj* pp){
    pp->a = 2;
    pp = NULL;
    cout << pp << endl;
}
int main() {
    obj* p = new obj();
    p->a = 1;
    cout << p << '\t' << p->a << endl;
    foo(p);
    cout << p << '\t' << p->a;
    return 0;
}
```

You'll note that the `p` stays the same after `foo` is executed although it was changed inside, since what was change was a copy of `p` while `a` was actually changed during `foo`

Answer (score 1):

The pointer is copied, but since that copy's value is still the same memory location, you can still modify the variable the copy points to.

Answer (score 1):

@CIsForCookies Nicely explained...

Adding a small detail:

> [...] or a copy of that pointer and hence every pointer should be assigned to null when not needed anymore?

Function parameters are variables local to the function, just as variables declared inside the function body. This means that their life time ends as soon as the function returns.

So setting any pointers to null right before returning is in vain as afterwards, the (copied) pointer simply won't exist any more...

Answer (score -1):

The pointer is just a number (like `int` variable), that *points* to a memory cell where the variable is stored (to the beginning of it actually). If you pass `int` variable into a function, you don't have to set it to `0` after usage, the compiler will do it for you.

Also if you pass a variable without a reference, it's most likely that a temporary copy will be used.

```
void test (VarType* ptr) {...}
```

You could use a const reference to a pointer, it would behave like a const reference to a variable:

```
void test (VarType* const& ptr) {...}
```

Comment: I don't see the point of a const-ref pointer parameter. It will still act as a pointer, and because it's const, you can't change what it points to... So, what's the point?

Comment: @EvanTeran AFAICS there is no real reason to form such an argument except as a by-product of templated code.

Comment: @EvanTeran: You might want to store the reference in order to monitor changes to the value of the pointer.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley clever, but likely not safe since the function will have no insight as to the lifetime of the pointer. It would be effectively reading memory that may or may not be valid randomly unless special precautions are taken... Which if you are willing to resort to, just use a `shared_ptr`

Comment: Not everything has to be safe. Just documented. Storing non-owning references or pointers to objects(including pointers) is very useful in many situations.

Comment: Why should a compiler zero out any variables after usage??? The variable is just left on the stack as is until it is overwritten during the next function call...

Comment: @BenjaminLindley sure, that's why I said "likely". I can't think of many situations where I would consider this a good idea... but that doesn't mean the situation doesn't exist. Generally, I would consider it dangerous as it is trivial to misuse, and not everyone reads documentation as much as they should. But that's my personal preference.

But as I said, if I truly need that type of construct, I'd use a `shared_ptr` so that it is impossible to misuse and trample memory as a result.

Comment: @Heavy, the details of this answer are wrong:

1. the compiler will typically not 0 anything for you after a call
2. passing a variable by pointer makes **no** temporary copies of the variable, (it does make a copy of the pointer though).
3. passing a vairable by const-ref pointer will **not** "behave like a const reference to a variable"

Comment: Thanks for the comments. That's what I meant, I just hadn't explained it properly.
I meant that the pointer is a variable itself, so you could pass a const reference to a pointer like to any other variable.